# What is "large margin optimization"?

Tags: math, statistics, machine-learning, regression

Could someone please explain what large margin optimization is, in a machine learning context? Everything I've found is extremely complicated and I don't know where to start.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

In classification, the largest margin problem is simply a search for the separating boundary (hyperplane in most cases) which maximizes the margin aroud it (minimum distance to the objects of each class).

In the simple case of two dimensional data, you can think of it like a search for such line, that correctly separates elements of one class from the other one, and in the same time maximizes the sum of distances to the closest points from both classes. Following image from wikipedia shows such separating line found using Support Vector Machine:

[image]

This geometrical concept is very important, as it makes solution unique - if we would simply search for a line that separates our data we would have infinitely many such solutions, and would have a problem to choose a particular one. Largest margin concept shows us exactly which line we want, and as a result, optimization process performed in this problem is generally repeatable (and as numerous experiments have shown - very effective).

Comment: I would love to see reason for a downvote